# detect string in bash

Tags: php, linux, string, bash

```
sample1=`expr "$filename" : '^sample-'`
sample2=`expr "$filename" : '.*sample\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$'`
if [ $sample1 -eq "0" ] && [ $sample2 -eq "0" ] && [[ `lsof -c unrar | grep $f` == "" ]] && [[ `lsof -c unzip | grep $f` == "" ]]
then
   ...
```

Ok so with this code I try detect files that start with sample-
or end with `sample.$random`

don't know why but sample2 is not working
I try to detect file that end with sample.*** but it will not work

Comment: Please explain in detail what does not work. I tried it, and both `expr` commands worked well.

Comment: so the idea is next is filename starts with sample- or ends with sample.mkv or sample.mp4 do not move the file

Comment: here is the code [link](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?ad9a2551859ed842#qgfQ2b/mog3WYIEV5GvCEFp8aiilZZ8dPTagFyM18Tc=)

Comment: Like Ethan, I tried the `expr` line and it works fine for me.  Give us a _specific_ example of a `filename` for which you think that the `expr` line is failing.

Comment: In this code you're using another regex: `'.*sample*'` which means all files of the form ...sample, ...samplee, ...sampleee, and so on.

Comment: sorry this is the link with code.. [link](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?353a9e2a0d866539#WN4uGT9KH8Njv1wH7lNkBdtvC7YiHQuEmeVweiNUDXM=) example: benidorm.s07e06.hdtv.x264-tla-sample.mp4

Comment: Since my first comment your code changed three times. I have the feeling that your question is a bit incomplete. Please, update your question, add the correct code, tell us your exact output and what you want to achieve. BTW: correct indentation could also help :-)

Comment: so the code is from last link what i try to achive is detecting files that have *sample* word inside of their filenames and do not move them

Answer (score 0):

Using the information found in the comments, you are interested in why this example does not match:

```
$ expr 'benidorm.s07e06.hdtv.x264-tla-sample.mp4' : '.*sample\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$'
0
```

The reason is that `mp4` does not match `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]`.  Try the following instead:

```
$ expr 'benidorm.s07e06.hdtv.x264-tla-sample.mp4' : '.*sample\.[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]$'
40
```

This succeeds.

Separately, note that, in the modern world of unicode fonts, regular expressions such as `[a-zA-Z]` should not be used.  If you want to match letters, use character classes such as `[[:alpha:]]` instead.

Comment: hmm i just did more tests whats interesting if .mp4 still moves the file if .mkv donest

Comment: @Jonn In computers, details are important, If you have specific filenames and you want to know why they match or don't match some specific regex, then please give me the details.